# What is the difference between url() and tuple for urlpatterns in Django?

Tags: python, django, url

So in Django the two lines of url code below work the same:

```
urlpatterns = patterns('',
    url(r'^login/$', 'django.contrib.auth.views.login'),
    (r'^login/$', 'django.contrib.auth.views.login')
)
```

AFAIK, the only difference is I can define `name='login'` so I can use it for reversing url. But besides this, is there any other differences?

Comment: to clarify, it is the `url` prefix that allows you to define the name

Answer (score 9, accepted):

There is no difference whatsoever. Have a look at the `patterns` function in `django.conf.urls.__init__.py`, if your url is a `list` or `tuple` then it is wrapped up by the `url` function anyway before being appended to the list of available patterns.